# How to append a single file in an Array to FormData?

Tags: javascript, form-data

I have a list of files that need to be uploaded to an AJAX call. I use `formData.append('uploads[]', fileList[i], names[i])` to do it.

If the `fileList` contains multiple files, the `uploads[]` received by server will be an array of files. This works perfect fine.

The problem is : If the `fileList` contains only one file, the server will get the file rather than an array of one file, which causes issue.

Any idea how can I put the file to an array when there is only one file?

Answer (score 1):

Just generate an array by wrapping your file into brackets...

```
formData.append('uploads[]', [fileList[i]], names[i])
```

or to be more precise, names should also be an array I guess:

```
formData.append('uploads[]', [fileList[i]], [names[i]])
```